# How to extract the text between two keywords in different lines using Perl

Tags: perl, extract, keyword

I have a file named `event.txt` and I need a Perl script to open it and read the lines between `tag1` and `tag2` keywords and print them on the screen.

I  have searched the forum and there are similar questions but I don't know how should I open the text file and do such a search.

Comment: Plz, give an example of file and desired result, that you want to get.

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't a place to get software written for free. If you don't know how to open a file then you don't know Perl at all, and you should either spend some time learning the language or pay someone to write a program for you. It is very discourteous of you to ask for work to be done for nothing when you don't stand a chance of doing it yourself.

Answer (score 2):

```
while (<>) {
  print if /tag1/../tag2/;
}
```

Comment: your solution is now working,since it is not including OPEN file  giving downvotes is the problem here ,as I linked someone else has hasked similar question and have got 7 upvotes,how comes?!

Comment: @KMHs: Perl uses the `<>` operator to read from the files named in the command line. You don't have to open the file explicitly.